# Django urls with https behind nginx proxy

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, django-rest-framework

I have django rest framework behind nginx proxy and some frontend on vue js. 
The problem is that I have urls with "http" but I need it to be "https":

```
"images": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/documents/2019/02/26/d59b9c8d-bb36-4461-97ad-7455f19637b8/FVbJkfww_Sk.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/documents/2019/02/26/902e5729-f7fd-480b-bf39-bca65a83038e/%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD.jpg"
            }
]
```

nginx is configured like that:

```
server {
     listen 8443 ssl;
     server_name  backend.mysite.net;
     client_max_body_size 3200m;
     proxy_connect_timeout 3000;
     proxy_send_timeout    3000;
     proxy_read_timeout    3000;
     send_timeout          3000;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
      }
```

My django config os below:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

Comment: how are those `urls` generated? Do you have `django.contrib.sites` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: In installed apps I have the following:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'mysite',
    'rest_framework',
    'social_django',
]

Comment: Ok. How are you generating those `urls`?

Comment: With  'rest_framework' I guess.

Comment: Good day. Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https` in your `location`

Update to

```
location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
  }
```

If that doesn't work try

```
location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
  }
```

Comment: No, that doesn't help.